# How to write a apex code for add name and lookup field on lead object (display both fields as one name)

Tags: concatenation, lookup

Apex nd trigger on lead object name+lookup field name

Import data from other object by list(case object) nd taking 2 for loops then compare , taking if condition for comparing lookup field in lead nd case then add both of them.